# Having trouble converting decimal to feet and inches with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to convert a decimal into feet and inches with jQuery and can't seem to find an answer. (This is in a Woocommerce shopping cart).

Here's my HTML:

```
<dd class="variation-Lengthyourequireft">
  <p>1.5</p>
</dd>
<dd class="variation-Lengthyourequireft">
  <p>2.5</p>
</dd>
```

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("dd.variation-Lengthyourequireft > p").each(function(){
        var thenum = parseFloat($(this).text()),
            feetvalue = Math.floor(thenum), // returns just the feet value
            inchvalue = Math.round(((thenum) % 1) * 12); // returns just the (inches)           

        $("dd.variation-Lengthyourequireft > p").text(feetvalue + "' " + inchvalue + "\"");
    });

});
```

I have the feet displaying correctly, but the inches returns a 0 (zero).

**Example:**

1'0". (It should be 1'6".) I was only getting NaN' NaN" before I added the `parseFloat()`.

I discovered one of the issues is having multiple instances of the same HTML tag (in this case `<dd class="variation-Lengthyourequireft">`)

Comment: I'm getting 6 for inchvalue. Can you add a snippet for us to see your results?

Comment: Working well for me, here is a quick fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/76h0xtrz/

Comment: Hmm, this is a real head scratcher. It works for me when I use an alert. The live site is www.steelbuildingcomponents.com. If you select sheeting or trim, choose a measurement (feet and inches) and add to cart, then view the cart, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Ran a few tries myself. First try it worked. When I added more, it went back to zeros.

Comment: I discovered that it doesn't work when multiple instances of the same HTML tag is there. Apologies for my newb-ness here, but if you add another instance of '<dd class="variation-Lengthyourequireft">' to Orel's fiddle, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Tony just replace the `$("dd.variation-Lengthyourequireft > p")` on the last line of the function with `$(this)` so you refer to the current `<p>` element in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function argument to `.text()` so that you change the text of each selected element based on its old value. The function receives the original text of the element as the second argument, and its return value replaces it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("dd.variation-Lengthyourequireft > p").text(function(i, oldText) {
    var thenum = parseFloat(oldText),
      feetvalue = Math.floor(thenum), // returns just the feet value
      inchvalue = Math.round(((thenum) % 1) * 12); // returns just the (inches)           

    return feetvalue + "' " + inchvalue + "\"";
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dd class="variation-Lengthyourequireft">
  <p>1.5</p>
</dd>
<dd class="variation-Lengthyourequireft">
  <p>2.5</p>
</dd>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @Rhumborl and Barmar. Both of your suggestions worked. However, when I implemented it, it still shows 0 for the inches. If you visit www.steelbuildingcomponents.com, shop for sheeting and add multiple instances to the cart, you'll see a javascript alert showing the measurements. I have two items in my cart and the alert displays 4 times. The first two show the 2 items' measurements in feet and inches correctly. But they loop through each other again, and show 0 for inches after that.

Comment: The jquery code was in the loop and re-calculating the measurements, causing the 0. When I realized that, I placed the code outside the loop, and it now works as it should. Appreciate the help! :)